# is it correct to say $\sum{(-1)^n*\cos(\ln(n)x)}=\operatorname{Re}[(1-2^{-ix})\zeta(1+ix)]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

The statement is that for a>0
$$\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}=\operatorname{Re}[(1-2^{1-(a+ix)}\zeta(a+ix))]$$
Here is how I got that stament

$$\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}=1-2^{1-s}\zeta(s))$$
then 
$$e^{\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}}=e^{1-2^{1-s}\zeta(s))}$$
$$\prod e^{\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}}=e^{1-2^{1-s}\zeta(s))}$$
Knowing that
To find the product of imaginary numbers you multiply the lengths and add the angles 
$$|e^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}}|=e^\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}$$
and that the angle 
$$\angle(e^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}})=\frac{(-1)^n\sin(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}$$
so
the magnitue is 
$$ e^{\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}}$$
and the angle is 
$$\sum\frac{(-1)^n*\sin(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}$$
whitch gives us 
$$e^{\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)+i(-1)^n\sin(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}}=e^{1-2^{1-s}\zeta(s))}$$
loging both sides we get 
$$\sum{\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)+i(-1)^n\sin(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}}={1-2^{1-s}\zeta(s))}$$
so 
$$\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}=\operatorname{Re}[(1-2^{1-(a+ix)}\zeta(a+ix)]$$
By braking up the cos you can make a bunch of other cool statments.

there are also a bunch of other cool statements you can make like
$$(1-2^{1-(a+ix)})\zeta(a+ix)+(1-2^{1-(a-ix)})\zeta(a-ix)+i[(1-2^{1-(a+ix)})\zeta(a+ix)-(1-2^{1-(a-ix)})\zeta(a-ix)]=(1-2)^{1-(a+ix)}\zeta(a+ix)$$

This is also super cool if we take $\sum\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)}{n^a}$ and squire it we get or at least i think we get 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)*(-1)^m\cos(\ln(m)x)}{n^a}$$
 if you do the same thing to sin and add them you get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\ln(n)x)*(-1)^m\cos(\ln(m)x)+(-1)^n\sin(\ln(n)x)*(-1)^m\sin(\ln(m)x)}{n^a}$$
whitch acoring to wolfram alfa is thought some algabric trickery
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(ln(m))*sin(ln(n))%2Bcos(ln(m))*cos(ln(n))

(we know they have the same sin becuse there multipled by the same negitve)
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{mn}\cos(\ln(\frac{n}{m})x)}{(mn)^a}$$

with means that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{mn}\cos(\ln(\frac{n}{m})x)}{(mn)^a}=\operatorname{MAG}[(1-2^{1-(a+ix)}\zeta(a+ix))]^2$$

and it just keeps getting cooler we can expencate both sides and get 
$$e^{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{mn}\cos(\ln(\frac{n}{m})x)}{(mn)^a}}=e^{\operatorname{MAG}[(1-2^{1-(a+ix)}\zeta(a+ix))]^2}$$
which is 
$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty e^{\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{mn}\cos(\ln(\frac{n}{m})x)}{(mn)^a}}=e^{\operatorname{MAG}[(1-2^{1-(a+ix)}\zeta(a+ix))]^2}$$
which is 
$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty*\prod_{m=0}^\infty e^{\frac{(-1)^{mn}\cos(\ln(\frac{n}{m})x)}{(mn)^a}}=e^{\operatorname{MAG}[(1-2^{1-(a+ix)}\zeta(a+ix))]^2}$$

Comment: Quick formatting tip:  Try using, (with dollar signs as you normally would) `\cos, \sin,  \ln, \angle,` as needed.  (Same applies to all trig functions, and many other functions as well.)

Comment: That would get you $cos(ln(n)x)$ render more nicely as $\cos(\ln(n)x)$, e.g.

Comment: cool thanks, I did not know I could do that I will fix it right away.

Comment: My pleasure; it's great you made the effort to format as best you could!

Comment: Yea that helped a lot thank you. Things can get really messy really quickly so formatting is super important so you don't make mistakes. Love any help I an get. missed the logs going to fix that now

Comment: Any advice for fixing real and imaginary?

Comment: I've seen a couple of ways used on this site.  There's a fancy script for R and I (Imaginary) that some use, but I can't recall the typeset.  Often, some will use `\operatorname{Re}(z)` which renders $\operatorname{Re}(z)$, and similarly using `\operatorname{Im}(z)`

Comment: Alright, I will give that a try, yea it worked thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as your previous question.

Trying to avoid complex numbers makes everything messy. Of course if it helps you to understand, good for you, but you should realize complex numbers make everything much cleaner.

> For $\Re(s) > 1$, $$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}, \qquad (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$$ This last series is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$ thus by analytic continuation the equality stays true for $\Re(s) > 0$, and for $a > 0, b \in \mathbb{R}$ $$\Re((1-2^{1-a-ib})\zeta(a+ib)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \Re(n^{-a-ib}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-a} \cos(b \ln n)$$
>    And hence
>   $$\Re((1-2^{1-a-ib})\zeta(a+ib))^2 = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+m} (nm)^{-a} \cos(b \ln n) \cos(b \ln m)$$
>   $$|(1-2^{1-a-ib})\zeta(a+ib)|^2 = (1-2^{1-a-ib})\zeta(a+ib)(1-2^{1-a+ib})\zeta(a-ib)\\=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+m} (nm)^{-a} (n/m)^{-ib}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+m} (nm)^{-a} \cos(b \log(n/m))$$
>    Where, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)^{-s}-(2n)^{-s}$ converges absolutely, changing the order of summation is allowed provided the terms stay grouped by two

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to complex number in infinite series. and am trying to relate it to something to which I am accustomed. I do however think I am starting to get the hang of it. also   ∑∞n=1(2n−1)−s−(2n)−s is super cool. I did not think of it that way until now.